# Error when converting Windows text file to Unix text file

Tags: unix

For converting Windows data file to Unix data file, I'm using `dos2unix` command but it's not executing. It's giving me the following message:

```
$ dos2unix new_request.txt testing.txt
ksh: dos2unix:  not found.
```

Answer (score 1):

You either don't have dos2unix or it is not in your system's path. Do one of the following:

- download dos2unix, maybe from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix/).
- put the dos2unix executable in the folder you're doing the conversion in.
- put dos2unix in your system path.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have `dos2unix` on your system, you can approximate it with

```
tr -d '\015' <dos.txt >unix.txt
```

The syntax for `tr` varies somewhat between systems; check that the output is what you expect, and consult the local `tr` man page if not. You want to remove the carriage return characters (ASCII 13, hex 0x0D, ctrl-M, aka `\r`) from the file.